# OtcFramework "Error finalizing setterHelper" exception when target leaf node is enum type in copy-source command

Tags: otcconverter, otcframework

Description:
While using copy-source command with the target-object-path leaf node is of type ENUM, then the custom helper method in the helper class is not recognised due to which the below error is thrown -

ERROR o.o.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl - Error while compiling OTCS file : ->org.iata.iata._2015._00._2018_1.airshoppingrs.AirShoppingRS_ar.ndc_21_3_4.IATAAirShoppingRS.otcs
org.otcframework.compiler.exception.SemanticsException: Error finalizing setterHelper in target 'setWeightUnitOfMeasurement' for : 'response.dataLists.baggageAllowanceList.baggageAllowance[].weightAllowance[].weightUnitOfMeasurement' - probable conflicts in command(s) [CP1]
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:87)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:108)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.lambda$process$0(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
at org.otcframework.compiler.GetterSetterFinalizer.process(GetterSetterFinalizer.java:57)
at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcLexicalizer.lexicalize(OtcLexicalizer.java:126)
at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.compileOtcFile(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:310)
at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.compileOtc(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:178)
at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.compile(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:136)
at org.otcframework.test.unit.CompilerTest.testCompile(CompilerTest.java:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
...
...
...

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Checked and found this to be a bug. File an issue at - https://github.com/frank-a-otc/otcframework/issues